# AngularJS with ngTable, testing with Intern

Tags: angularjs, intern, ngtable

I am trying to setup intern testing for my angularjs app that has ngTable dependency.

So my test file for AccountController:

```
define([
   'intern/chai!expect',
   'intern!bdd',
   'intern/order!nonNgDependencies/non-angular-dependencies.min.js',
   'intern/order!angular/angular',
   'intern/order!angular-mocks/angular-mocks',
   'intern/order!ui.router/release/angular-ui-router',
   'intern/order!ngResource/angular-resource',
   'intern/order!bower_components/ng-table/dist/ng-table.js',
   'intern/order!im/app',
   'intern/order!im/account/AccountService',
   'intern/order!im/account/AccountController'
], function (expect, bdd) {

     function inject (fn) {
       return function () {
          angular.injector(['ng', 'ngMock', 'ui.router', 'ngTable', 'IntegrationManager']).invoke(fn);
       }
     }

     bdd.describe('AccountController', function () {
         var ctrl, scope;

       bdd.beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
         scope = $rootScope.$new();
         ctrl = $controller('AccountController', { $scope: scope });
       }));

       bdd.it('should return true', function () {
         expect(scope.isTrue()).to.true;
       });

       bdd.it('should not have Accounts to start', function () {
         expect(scope.accounts).to.be.undefined;
       });

     });

});
```

My internjs config file:

```
 // Learn more about configuring this file at <https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Configuring-Intern>.
 // These default settings work OK for most people. The options that *must* be changed below are the
 // packages, suites, excludeInstrumentation, and (if you want functional tests) functionalSuites.
define({
// The port on which the instrumenting proxy will listen
proxyPort: 9000,

// A fully qualified URL to the Intern proxy
proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',

// Default desired capabilities for all environments. Individual capabilities can be overridden by any of the
// specified browser environments in the `environments` array below as well. See
// https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities for standard Selenium capabilities and
// https://saucelabs.com/docs/additional-config#desired-capabilities for Sauce Labs capabilities.
// Note that the `build` capability will be filled in with the current commit ID from the Travis CI environment
// automatically
capabilities: {
    'selenium-version': '2.41.0'
},

// Browsers to run integration testing against. Note that version numbers must be strings if used with Sauce
// OnDemand. Options that will be permutated are browserName, version, platform, and platformVersion; any other
// capabilities options specified for an environment will be copied as-is
environments: [
    // { browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '11', platform: 'Windows 8.1' },
    // { browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '10', platform: 'Windows 8' },
    // { browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '9', platform: 'Windows 7' },
    // { browserName: 'firefox', version: '28', platform: [ 'OS X 10.9', 'Windows 7', 'Linux' ] },
    { browserName: 'chrome', version: '34', platform: [ 'OS X 10.9', 'Windows 7', 'Linux' ] },
    // { browserName: 'safari', version: '6', platform: 'OS X 10.8' },
    // { browserName: 'safari', version: '7', platform: 'OS X 10.9' }
],

// Maximum number of simultaneous integration tests that should be executed on the remote WebDriver service
maxConcurrency: 3,

// Name of the tunnel class to use for WebDriver tests
tunnel: 'SauceLabsTunnel',

tunnelOptions: {
'username': '*****',
'accessKey': '**********************'
},

// The desired AMD loader to use when running unit tests (client.html/client.js). Omit to use the default Dojo
// loader
useLoader: {
    'host-node': 'dojo/dojo',
    'host-browser': 'node_modules/dojo/dojo.js'
},

// Configuration options for the module loader; any AMD configuration options supported by the specified AMD loader
// can be used here
loader: {
    // Packages that should be registered with the loader in each testing environment
    packages: [ 
        { name: 'im', location: 'js/src' },
        { name: 'angular', location: 'bower_components/angular' },
        { name: 'angular-mocks', location: 'bower_components/angular-mocks' },
        { name: 'ui.router', location: 'bower_components/angular-ui-router' },
        { name: 'ngTable', location: 'bower_components/ng-table/dist' },
        { name: 'ngResource', location: 'bower_components/angular-resource' },
        { name: 'nonNgDependencies', location: 'tests'}
    ]
},

// Non-functional test suite(s) to run in each browser
suites: [ 'tests/all' ],

// Functional test suite(s) to run in each browser once non-functional tests are completed
functionalSuites: [ /* 'myPackage/tests/functional' */ ],

// A regular expression matching URLs to files that should not be included in code coverage analysis
excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:tests|bower_components|node_modules)\//
});
```

The error I get when trying to run intern is:

```
 undefined: Failed to load module angular/main from /bower_components/angular/main.js (parent: bower_components/ng-table/dist/ng-table)
 Error: Failed to load module angular/main from /bower_components/angular/main.js (parent: bower_components/ng-table/dist/ng-table)
  at HTMLScriptElement.handler  <__intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:731:13>
 No unit test coverage for chrome 34.0.1847.116 on Windows NT
```

From the error, my guess is that it isn't able to load ngTable, however I am not sure where to start.

Any advice on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: If there is anything I should add or any details that would help, please let me know

Comment: Personally, I'd use Protractor for testing AngularJS apps. That's what it is built for.